# Access Select Query to show the same field with a different criteria

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a select query in Access 2010 which shows a 'Level Name' where the 'Period ID' is set to 1

How can i add another field to the query which also shows the Level Name where the Period ID is set to 2?

I would like them both to be next to each other in separate rows

For reference, my current query looks like:

```
SELECT 
    qryMaster.[First Name] & " " & qryMaster.[Last Name] AS ChildName, 
    qryMaster.LevelName
FROM 
    qryMaster
WHERE 
    (
        (qryMaster.ClassID = [Forms]![frmViewRecords_subject]![cboClass]) 
        AND   
        (qryMaster.SubjectID = [Forms]![frmViewRecords_subject]![cboSubject]) 
        AND  
        (qryMaster.PeriodID = 1)
    );
```

[image: Pic of how my current Query looks in a subform]

I have added a picture of how my current query looks like in a sub form. I would like a new **Column** next to september, but for a different period

Comment: Could you please add some sample data of how it is in your table and how you want the result to be?

Comment: I have added a picture to the question above

Comment: You mean a Column.. Row is `Lewis Hilton - 40-60 Emerging`. Column is `September`.

Comment: So could Connor Clark have record for both `September` and `November` (per say)?

Answer (score 1):

A WHERE clause is always for all fields. So if you want two different WHERE clauses then you need two queries.

Otherwise try

```
AND (qryMaster.PeriodID In(1,2))
```

Comment: Although this is a solution to one problem, how do you reckon on tackling the two column PeriodID1 belonging to ColumnX and PeriodID 2 in ColumnY?

Comment: That is the first part of my answer. You can’t have PeriodID1 belonging to ColumnX and PeriodID 2 in ColumnY in one query - at least I think so.
I think if you really want this then run two separate queries and write the results into one table with two fields or if you want them for a ListBox then add the items of the list box in code.

Comment: For info, i have achieved what i wanted by writing the writing the results to a new table and creating a sub form based on the new table as suggested by Edgar...Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread was active five month ago, but I had the same problem, found this page with google. Asuming others will arrive here too, I'll post the two solutions that I found below.

```
SELECT t1.ChildName, t1.LevelName1, qryMaster.LevelName
FROM
    ((SELECT 
        qryMaster.[First Name] & " " & qryMaster.[Last Name] AS ChildName, 
        qryMaster.LevelName as LevelName1
    FROM qryMaster
    WHERE 
    (
        (qryMaster.ClassID = [Forms]![frmViewRecords_subject]![cboClass]) 
        AND   
        (qryMaster.SubjectID = [Forms]![frmViewRecords_subject]![cboSubject]) 
        AND  
        (qryMaster.PeriodID = 1)
    )) AS t1)
LEFT JOIN qryMaster
ON t1.ChildName = (qryMaster.[First Name] & " " & qryMaster.[Last Name])
WHERE (
    (qryMaster.ClassID = [Forms]![frmViewRecords_subject]![cboClass]) 
    AND   
    (qryMaster.SubjectID = [Forms]![frmViewRecords_subject]![cboSubject]) 
    AND  
    (qryMaster.PeriodID = 2)
)
```

As I do not have your data I couldn't test the code for your data, therefore I am not sure whether the "ON" clause works like this. In my case I have some customer ID there.

And the second one:

```
SELECT t1.[First Name] & " " & t1.[Last Name] AS ChildName, t1.LevelName AS LevelName1, t2.levelName AS LevelName2
FROM qryMaster t1
    INNER JOIN qryMaster t2 ON t1.Childname=(t2.[First Name] & " " & t2.[Last Name])
WHERE (
    (t1.ClassID = [Forms]![frmViewRecords_subject]![cboClass]) AND  
    (t1.SubjectID = [Forms]![frmViewRecords_subject]![cboSubject]) AND
    (t1.PeriodID = 1) AND
    (t2.ClassID = [Forms]![frmViewRecords_subject]![cboClass]) AND  
    (t2.SubjectID = [Forms]![frmViewRecords_subject]![cboSubject]) AND
    (t2.PeriodID = 2)
)
```